# Как исключить одно свойство при наследовании интерфейсов?

Tags: typescript

Как я могу наследовать интерфейс `IPerson`, взяв от туда все свойства, кроме `parents`?

```
interface IPerson {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  parents: Array<string>;
}

interface IAlex extends IPersong {
  status?: string;
  place?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получение нового типа, без определенных свойств, можно воспользоваться типом [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys)

```
interface IAlex extends Omit<IPerson, 'parents'> {
```

В данном случае у результирующего типа будет отсутствовать свойство `parents`

[**Пример**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAVoGcD2JkDeAUMsiHALYQBcyWYUoA5gNwnJxM1kCuFARtDakADnCgRwWWgEEoUOAE8APPUYgmAPjYBfIkVCRYiFKhkAbCAA9k1yCAAmWZAHkKwMMozY8AGgDkYhJS-pqE7PRwYDxYAPy0aszCyCLmJvF0DElEekQAbuIc1GaWNgC84aSk5FS0-nD+vuyknNwAjAAMTTpAA)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, помогло

Comment: а как, например, наследовать интерфейсы с определенными свойствами? Например, с типом RequestHeaders, Promise и тд? Какой тип в этом случае нужно написать?

Comment: @Alexandr_Yakovlev, не понял вопрос. Попробуй задать новый вопрос с примером того что хочешь получить